# Show that $x \leq f(x)$ where $<$ is a well ordering

Tags: set-theory

I'm stuck on this question: let $<$ be a well ordering on a set $A$ and let $f$ be an operator on $A$ satisfying $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$. I need to prove $x \leq f(x)$ for each $x \in A$. A suggestion is to consider $f(f(x))$, and I wanted to use a contradicton argument but I see no leads. Is there any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the set $A'=\{a\in A\mid f(a)<a\}$ is non-empty. Let $x$ be the smallest element of $A'$. Then we have $f(x)<x$, and therefore $f(f(x))<f(x)$, so $f(x)\in A'$. But this contradicts $x$ being the smallest element of $A'$.

Comment: That's very helpful! Can we say that for every $x$ in $A$ there exists such a subset $A'$ where $x$ is least in $A'$? That would finish the proof.

Comment: @DrunkPolice No, that's completely unnecessary. But yes, $\{x\}$ is such a set.

Comment: I would think it is necessary cus we need this to fold for all $x$, no? If it's not, can you explain?

Comment: @DrunkPolice We want to show that $A'$, as defined, is empty. We do this by showing that it cannot have a minimal element. There is no "for all $x$", there is only the single $x$ which is the smallest element of the assumed non-empty $A'$.

Comment: Yep! I understand it now. Thank you so much!